# How to display only ID field Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I would like to solve a little problem with `Django` and `QuerySet`.

I have in my views this command :

```
query_car = Car.objects.get(pk=value)
```

But I want to get only one field from the `CarModels`, for example : `color` or another one but just one.

How I can handle my script in order to do that ?

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [.values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values)

example:

```
 query_car = Car.objects.filter(pk=value).values('color')
```

Comment: I get this error : `Exception Value: 
'Car' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: That's because I used `get()`, `values()` should be used with `filter()`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [only()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#only) method.

Like so:

`query_car = Car.objects.only("color").get(pk=value)`

Comment: I get always the same result : `2 Audi Red` instead of `Red`

Comment: Right because `.get(pk=value)` will only return the object you are getting (in this case, it sounds like a pk of 2). If you want all of the cars, just remove that last bit.